# SwiftUI: Open a full screen View (i.e. hide SideBar) from a NagivationLink

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, sidebar

I've been digging through the apple docs for a way to open a View from a NavigationLink where the SideBar is collapsed by default.

Everything I've tried leaves the side bar visible (but collapsible by pressing the sidebar button). I would like the default behaviour to be that the SideBar is not visible.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: "attach" `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` to your `NavigationView`

Comment: Thanks - that "kind of" does what I'm after (I Could be wanting too much). This results in the back button disappearing, and there is no way to navigate back. When I attach ".navigationBarBackButtonHidden(false)" to it, nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears that the only way to come close to this (closing the sidebar when an NavLink is clicked in the sidebar) is to attach this to the NavigationView:

```
NavigationView {
   ...
}
 .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

While this isn't quite what I was after, using this style I can use an Stack to establish a "Home" view to the right of the NavigationLinks to serve close the the purpose I had in mind.

I hope that helps someone out there.

Comment: this things work in the iPhone and iPad app, but not working for macOS app, mac app does not have this option available. How I can achieve this thing in the macOS app?